# How to pass data using checkbox from view to controller laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

The interface that showed is using @foreach method to display . Hence , i want to know how to pass only one checkbox (view) into controller.

Below is the view coding.

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
<tr>
<td>{{ $article->jenis_simptom}}</td>
<td style="width: 10px">
<input type="checkbox" value="{{ $article->jenis_simptom}}" name="{{ $article->id }">
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Thank You

[Here is the dummy interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO3QJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use articles[] as html field name with $article->id as a key

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $article->jenis_simptom}}</td>
        <td style="width: 10px">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $article->jenis_simptom}}" name="articles[{{ $article->id }]">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

In your controller you'll be able to loop thru submitted array which will contain only elements that were `checked` in your html

```
foreach ($request->input('articles') as $key => $value) {
    // $key will contain your article id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Collective forms. If you're using Laravel 4, it works out of the box, for Laravel 5 you should [install the package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#installation).

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'Controller@store')) !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('name', 'value') !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Send') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When user submits the form, `store` action of `Controller` catches all form data, including checked checkboxes and puts it in `$request` variable.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
```